# Receiving an error with Git on Windows: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_readbytes:sslv3 errno 0

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab, tls1.2

A member within my group is constantly getting the below error when attempting to push to our GitLab repository:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_readbytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
```

It works sometimes when pushing in small segments, however, I'd much prefer that it was pushed in one go. And, it works perfectly fine for myself.

I was wondering if someone would be able to shed some light as to why this error keeps occurring and how to fix the issue. I initially assumed it was to do with file sizes or interent speed which, unless I'm using the below incorrectly (which is likely); was not the case.

The size of the push is approximately 40MB (and around 158 objects)

We have tried a few solutions with no success, including:

- Setting `git config http.sslVersion` (Although it appears as though this doesn't change when using `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2` as it continues to show it using `TLSv1.3`)
- Setting `git config http.postBuffer`
- Using SSH instead of HTTPS
- Disabling the firewall (works sometimes)

If it's any additional help we're working on Unreal Engine projects with a suitable `.gitignore` file. And we're using GitLab to host our project on a private repository. We also use VisualStudio Code with their built-in git source control.

Below is a segment of the `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2` log (this is just before it attempts to retry the connection):

```
* OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
* Failed receiving HTTP2 data
* Connection died, retrying a fresh connect
* Closing connection 0
```

And the very last line in the error log is:

```
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
* OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
* Failed receiving HTTP2 data
* OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, errno 0
* Failed sending HTTP2 data
* Connection #1 to host gitlab.com left intact
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Feel free to ask if I can provide any more information. I'd be more than happy to provide.
I must admit my expertise with git/curl/openssl is quite limited so I'm not 100% certain on what I should be looking for in terms of errors.